# Parametro ..Lista de listas.. y promedios

Tags: haskell

Quisiera saber como hago en haskell para pasar por parametro una lista de listas..? Y  para sacar promedios con esas listas ? Necesito que me  devuelva solo una lista que tenga los promedios de cada una de las listas que contiene la lista.. osea.. [[8,6],[6,2,4]] = 
[7,5]... graciass!

Comment: Hola Pam, ayúdanos agregando en tus preguntas lo que has tratado o investigado, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Si una lista tiene como tipo *genérico* `[a]`, entonce una lista de listas sería `[[a]]`.

Para sacar un promedio de listas, se puede hacer así:

```
promedios :: Fractional a => [[a]] -> [a]
promedios xss = map promedio xss
  where
    promedio [] = 0
    promedio xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
```